# Apache2 show localhost as mydomainname.com

Tags: apache2

I want to record a screencast of a website but it is not live yet. Is it possible in Apache2 to temporarily change localhost to make it look like its the actual web address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an entry in /etc/hosts that resolves to the localhost

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

E.g.
`127.0.0.1  localhost loopback whateverilike.com`

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can use [your hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to point the domain name to 127.0.0.1.